# Error while exporting github project to apk

Tags: java, android, github, apk

Hi I tried to export a project file into apk, its an open source code from github when I try to export i get this following error, can someone help

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':AmbilWarna:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

  > When running gradle with java 5, 6 or 7, you must set the path to jdk8, either with property retrolambda.jdk or environment variable JAVA8_HOME
- Try:

  ## Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':AmbilWarna:compileRetrolambdaRelease'.

  > Directory 'C:\Users\Rao\Desktop\androdaltika\androidbible-develop\AmbilWarna\build\retrolambda\release' specified for property 'inputDir' does not exist.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the GitHub repo as well please?

Comment: https://github.com/yukuku/androidbible/

Comment: Why not delete/remove the AmbilWarna folder/module and add this to your dependencies: `compile 'com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0.1'` ?

Comment: i have deleted the folder and added com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0.1 to the dependecies and hence i recieve this error Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':Alkitab'.
> Cannot evaluate module AmbilWarna : Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Comment: Ok, let me try to recreate your error and I'll get back to you with a solid solution. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to create your own bible for android with custom YET files?

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to reproduce your original error. The APK generated successfully. Did you change anything after importing the github repo?

Comment: @SteveC. No sir, all i done was after importing the zip file i clicked the > alkitab folder and went to build in menu and build apk and so i generated those errors, let me know if i have generated something wrong?

Comment: I pretty much did the same thing. I downloaded the zip, imported the project and clicked build. Do you have the most recent SDK and Android studio build?

Comment: @SteveC. yes sir, i do have while did you delete the ambitwarna? and performed it

Comment: no, I wanted to try to reproduce your original error first. Can you try reimporting the project? I wanna make sure we're on the same page

Comment: @SteveC. yes sir I re-imported the project to the studio and clicked on the alkitab and clicked build and i received the same error as said before at beginning

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't reproduce your error or figure out what is giving you that error. The only thing I can think of is that your Gradle plugin is being run in offline mode. Your error is referencing the project wide needed me.tatarka.retrolambda plugin. Do you have your JAVA home variable set?

Comment: At this point, I'm not sure what else to offer. Maybe after some sleep I can re-approach this with a clear mind. You can also try to contact their help line here: `help@bibleforandroid.com`

Comment: @SteveC. sure thank you